# regarding Outlook 2013 API.

Tags: azure, outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

Would it be possible to obtain, create, update and delete the events on the calendar with REST API for Office 2013 Outlook?

It seems it is possible by integrating On-premises and Azure AD that is written in this link 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis), would you confirm if my understanding is correct.

Or should I use API for Outlook.com to synchronize with Outlook 2013?

Overall, I would like to learn if there is an API for 2013.
And if there is not, how can I synchronize Office 2013 with Outlook.com?

Thank you very much for your help on this. 
I’m new to Outlook and please advise if my questions are not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the mailboxes are located.

If they are in Office 365, then you can use the REST based Microsoft Graph APIs or the Outlook REST APIs.

If the mailboxes are located in an on-premises Exchange server, then you can only use the Exchange Web Services API. Since you mention Outlook 2013, I'm also assuming Exchange 2013. The EWS API documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900168(v=exchg.150).aspx).

If you use .NET, I recommend to use the [EWS Managed API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices/) to implement an EWS client.